# Using .HTACCESS Rewrite Rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite URLs for my dynamically generated PHP site.

I load new templates into `index.php` by using the following GET:

```
localhost/dmk/?req=signin
localhost/dmk/?req=useraccount
```

I want these links to appear as:

```
localhost/dmk/signin
localhost/dmk/useraccount
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this. Everything I try either produces a 500 Internal Server Error, or has no effect at all.

I must be missing the point of `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteRule ^dmk/(.+)$ dmk/?req=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

This would redirect any URL like `/dmk/page` that does not conflict with an existing file or directory to `/dmk/?req=page`. I'm assuming your `index.php` is in `/dmk` directory.

Comment: This is giving me a 500 Internal Error.

Comment: What's the location of your htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You should read some documentation in this direction. I know it's a bit frustrating at first to write the rules, but it gets easier. You need to learn regular expressions to write the rules (you can start here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

As for the rules you need, they go like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^signin$ index.php?req=signin [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^useraccount$ index.php?req=useraccount [L,QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(signin|useraccount)$ index.php?res=$1 [L,QSA]
```

You can paste the rules you have used, maybe someone will explain you what you did wrong.

Comment: This doesn't have any effect.

Comment: If your htaccess is not in dmk/ you should change the rules like `^dmk/signin$ dmk/index.php?req=signin`